# How to downgrade Lenovo Tab M10 to Android 11

Tags: android-11, android-12, lenovo

We have several Lenovo Tab 10/Android 11 at my office, running a home made application. Two of them upgraded to Android 12 and the application stopped working. At certain point it just quits without any message.

Is there a way to reflash to Android 11? IT guys can't find the reason of the induced bug and in the meanwhile we need all the tablets up and running. We disabled automatics updates.

Comment: If it is a home-made app you should have the source, so the common way would be to fix the problem and make it run on Android 12, instead of downgrading the OS. Check `adb logcat` for the error/stack trace and then post a question together with the problematic code on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: As @Robert suggests you shouldn't downgrade. The application you are talking about, can you be more specific? All the applications are crashing just or an application used for your office stuffs? If all are crashing you should try asking on https://forums.lenovo.com

Comment: It's a specific app developed by our IT team. It ran smoothly under Android 11, but after the update it just crashes. No message, no nothing. logcat does not show anything. It does not even includes the app. IT guys are looking for the problem but AFAI it happens the same when they run the app, crashes  
It is a survey app developed with Delphi 10.4. When the camera is turned on, a few images are shown on screen and then the app just quits. According to IT guys, the app does nothing when the images are displaying. Just waiting for the user to click a button. Again: it ran fine until upgraded